# How to call LogEvent with AnalyticsEventScreenView in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

The blog post at https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/08/google-analytics-manual-screen-view.html mentions that calling SetCurrentScreen is depricated.

Is this also the case for Firebase Analytics in Unity? I can't seem to call LogEvent with AnalyticsEventScreenView parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that as of September 24th the Unity SDK is not yet fully updated to use the latest iOS SDK.

But if you manually update the `Podfile` to use version `6.29.0` ([which is when it was introduced](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_6290_-_july_28_2020)) like this:

```rb
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.29.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.29.0'
end
```

You can then manually use it like this:

```cs
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("screen_view", 
new Firebase.Analytics.Parameter("screen_name", name));
```